# How to convert from Word to PDF format via javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to convert a word file to pdf format on the fly, when a user downloads it from the server.

Is there a way to do it using javascript?

I am using [DNN Sharp](http://www.dnnsharp.com/).

Comment: with java script!? why javascript?

Comment: Just to clarify, is your core problem that you have some DNN Sharp module that can only produce files in Word document format, and you instead want to allow the user to download PDF versions of those Word documents, presumably because they are harder to modify?

Comment: Yes, that my concern

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do this using client-side-javascript as client-side-javascript don't have access of your file system.

If you want to do it with javascript only then you can use node-webkit

Comment: How can I use node-webkit ?

Comment: You can have a look at "https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/". node-webkit is wrapper over node and mainly used for desktop applications.